# Number of machine cycles required for RET instruction in 8085?

Tags: assembly

How many number of machine cycles are required for the RET instruction in [8085](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8085#Programming_model)?

Why does it require that many number of cycles?

Answer (score 2):

The RET instruction needs 3 machine cycles. One to fetch and decode the instruction (4 T states), and two more machine cycles (that is, 2*3 = 6 T states) to read two bytes from the stack (stack is exterior to microprocessor, stack is in read-write memory, so to exchange data with stack needs machine cycles). Thus, the RET instruction needs a total of 3 machine cycles and 10 T-states.

Ref.: *[How many machine cycles are required for RET instruction in 8085 microprocessor is ?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_machine_cycles_are_required_for_RET_instruction_in_8085_microprocessor_is)* (sic).

Answer (score 1):

The RET instruction takes 10 cycles, according to the table at this site: http://www.cavehill.uwi.edu/fpas/cmp/online/el21c/lesson18.html

The instruction requires 3 memory fetches, one for the opcode and 2 for the return address, with each fetch taking 3 cycles (or more if the memory requires wait states). The opcode decode takes one cycle more.

Comment: 10 *clock* cycles I presume? (The other answer introduces some confusion by talking about *machine* cycles. The question does too, but perhaps what was really asked for was *clock* cycles. *Clock* cycles are needed when making assembler programs whereas machine cycles are only for curiosity(?).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, yes that's clock cycles. I've never heard cycles referred to in any other manner.