# 8085; Why RET doesn't require a 6 T-states Fetch cycle like CALL?

Tags: assembly, call, cpu-architecture, 8085, micro-architecture

The `CALL` instruction, requires 5 machine cycles, namely, `OPCODE-FETCH, MEMORY READ, MEMORY READ, MEMORY WRITE, MEMORY WRITE`. The OPCODE-FETCH cycle of CALL has 6 T-states [to take care of the decrements of  the Stack Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773146/9622343).

`RET` instruction [requires, 3 machine cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127748/number-of-machine-cycles-required-for-ret-instruction-in-8085), `OPCODE-FETCH, MEMORY READ, MEMORY READ`, even here, the microprocessor's got to **increment** the stack pointer **twice, as before**, to pop. But, the OPCODE-FETCH cycle only has 4 T-states, Why is that?

I've got a vague idea, as to why; in `CALL` and `PUSH` the SP has to be decremented first, unlike `RET` or `POP`. This first decrement alone is taken care in the last two T-states of `FETCH` cycle. But why would that require two T-states. Again, I'm really not sure about this. Kindly help.

Comment: Documentation to explain what's happening in each T cycle isn't easy to find. But incrementing/decrementing the stack pointer isn't the only thing going on. My guess is that CALL is special because the value of the PC needs end up on the stack _and_ also be reset to the branch address. It's likely the extra states are there because those operations share a bus and so must be sequential. For RET, the value from the stack just goes to the PC. It's a simpler operation.

Comment: @Gene Yeah, I agree, I also, couldn't find anything. "value of the PC needs end up on the stack" Isn't that why `CALL` two separate machine cycles ?

Comment: `ret` is shorter, right?  Just a single-byte opcode instead of also taking an immediate displacement, same as in 8086?  Or do the "memory read" machine cycles account for fetching the operand?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, it's is shorter, sorry I haven't learnt 8086 yet. I don't understand the last sentence, It has 2 Memory Reads to place the data pointed SP in PC right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the memory read cycles for `call 16-bit-target`.  That's part of decoding to fetch the target address after seeing the `call` opcode I assume.  Other than that `call` doesn't need to read memory.

Comment: You might consider asking this on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is a duplicate and already answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466032/8085-why-ret-doesnt-require-a-6-t-states-fetch-cycle)